# Foundation grid system not working inside a td

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5, grid-system

My web page has a table and for one  element i have to apply grid property of foundation. I have to divide the row into two columns having size 10 and 2. First column is an input field and second is a drop down icon, But when I try to do it 2nd column is going down after first column.

```
<table class="inner-table">
    <tr>
        <td width="20">plan </td>
        <td width="50">Mobile</td>
        <td width="15">20%</td>
        <td width="15">50%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>dsffgh</td>
        <td>Mobile</td>
        <td>20%</td>
        <td>50%</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>Plan</td>
        <td>
            <div class="row">
            <form class="project-name">
                <div class="small-11 columns">
                    <input type="text" name="projectName">
                </div>
                <div class="small-1 columns">
                    <a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1"><img src="images/Rectangle-13.png" alt="dropdown-menu" height="10em" width="10em">
                    </a>                    
                    <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
                    <li>10</li>
                    <li>15<li>
                    <li>20</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="dot-emp3" class="show-more">
            ...
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaaOxG

Comment: I don't know about Zurb. But I see that there's an error in your code for the `<img>`, making the picture come out at 10x10 pixels instead of ems.

Comment: Generally it goes down because of not enough space. In foundation.css .column, .columns  have padding left and padding-right, set 4 times, reset those properties to 0, unless you really need these paddings